# Installing python program in AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Postgresql gives pg_config error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a python application which uses Postgresql. I used psycopg2 library (v 2.8.4) when doing the development, but when trying to install it on the beanstalk, it gives the following error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

  python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
```

Anyone have idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the question. Instead of installing the `psycopg2` directly, use `psycopg2-binary==2.8.4`.

Similar question is also being asked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/caceoa/pg_config_error_when_trying_to_deploy_django_app/)